# Suma desde input

Tags: javascript

Busco ingresar tres precios de productos y mostrar la suma de los mismos.

```
var productoUno;
var productoDos;
var productoTres;

productoUno= PrecioUno.value;
productoDos= PrecioDos.value;
productoTres= PrecioTres.value;


productoUno=parseInt(productoUno);
productoDos=parseInt(productoDos);
productoTres=parseInt(productoTres);

suma=(productoUno+productoDos+productoTres);

alert("la suma es" +suma);
```

No funciona, alguien podria orientarme un poco? estoy bastante perdido

PrecioUno, PrecioDos y PrecioTres los saque del codigo html.

```
<form id="FormIngreso" class=" animated bounceInLeft" class=" animated bounceInLeft"class=" animated bounceInLeft">
       <h1>Ferrete facturación</h1>
                <input type="text"  placeholder="Ingrese Precio" id="PrecioUno">
                <input type="text"  placeholder="Ingrese Precio" id="PrecioDos">
                <input type="text"  placeholder="Ingrese Precio" id="PrecioTres">
                <br>
```

Cuando quiero realizar la suma en la pagina web, ingreso los 3 precios en las 3 casillas y cuando apreto el boton de sumar no ocurre nada.

Comment: de donde sale `PrecioUno`? que es lo que falla?

Comment: Es el Id, veniamos haciendo programas similares que sacamos el ID del codigo html para reemplazar en la pagina. No se si me explico bien, cuando quiero realizar la suma en la pagina no sucede nada

Comment: por favor edita tu pregunta y explica mejor la parte del error, es decir lo que debería salir y lo que esta pasando, además explica la parte del código que te pregunté

Comment: ahi edité lo mejor que pude

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código de tu botón?

Answer (score 1):

Es por como tienes definido tu código. Acostumbra a manejar las acciones, como en este caso a sumar, mediante eventos.

El tener el código de corrido en javascrit es decir que lo ejecutaras al momento de que se cargue la ventana. Al momento de cargar la ventana no tienes los precios escritos en los inputs.

[Cree un botón y le asigne una función al evento click](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp). La función [toma los datos de los inputs](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) y realiza la suma y la muestra en un alert.

```js
var productoUno = document.getElementById("PrecioUno");
var productoDos = document.getElementById("PrecioDos");
var productoTres = document.getElementById("PrecioTres");
var btnResultado = document.getElementById("btnResultado");

btnResultado.onclick = function () {
  productoUno= parseInt(PrecioUno.value);
  productoDos= parseInt(PrecioDos.value);
  productoTres= parseInt(PrecioTres.value);

  suma = productoUno + productoDos + productoTres;
  alert(`La suma es ${suma}`);
};
```

```html
<h1>Ferrete facturación</h1>
<input type="text"  placeholder="Ingrese Precio" id="PrecioUno" /> +
<input type="text"  placeholder="Ingrese Precio" id="PrecioDos" /> +
<input type="text"  placeholder="Ingrese Precio" id="PrecioTres" />
<button type="button" id="btnResultado" >Resultado</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que veo, si es que tu código está completo, es que no tomas los elementos del HTML en las variables para después manipularlos.

Eso es posible usando el **DOM**, es decir, "convertir" tus etiquetas html en objetos para asi manipularlos desde JS.

Tomando tu caso, tendrías que tomar la etiqueta HTML de la siguiente forma:

```
var productoUno = document.querySelector('#PrecioUno');
```

Como ves, con el método **querySelector** puedes tomar un elemento HTML aparir de su clase, id o solo especificando la etiqueta (Ej: body, head, nav).

Después de haber "guardado" tu etiqueta en la variable te quedaría obtener su valor a partir de la propiedad *value*.

```
productoUno.value
```